# How to get a random float with x decimal digits in PHP?

Tags: php

How to get a random float between a range with x decimal digits in PHP?

For example, how can I get a random float with 5 decimal digits between 0 and 20?

Comment: Get a rand between 0 and 2000000, then divide by 100000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution Mark Baker suggested is probably the best. Also you don't have to hard-code these big numbers to improve readability:

```
$min = 0;
$max = 20;
$decimals = 5;

$divisor = pow(10, $decimals);
$randomFloat = mt_rand($min, $max * $divisor) / $divisor;
```

I just wonder why do you need exactly 5 decimals. If it's just for a presentation, that means you're going to output it as a string, you can use this solution:

```
$num = $min + lcg_value() * ($max - $min);
$randomFloat = sprintf("%+.5f", $num);
```

PHP function [`lgc_value`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php) returns random a (pseudo) random float number in the range of (0, 1). Function [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) returns a string procued according to the format. `%+.5f` means float number with 5 decimals.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. The 5 decimals were just an example. At the moment I don't know how many I need.

Comment: Sure, therefore I proposed to use `$decimals` instead of these big numbers. My concern was why do you need exact number of decimals. I guess it's for a presentation, not for further calculations. In that case you can use `sprintf`, which returns number as a `string`, which is perfectly fine for output. BTW you can cast it back to `float` of course, but it's not so nice :)